# How to filter a csv datafile with pandas

Tags: python

I have read a csv file into Python as df and saved it as a new data frame called Master_Clean.

The csv file contains information about job listings. I've attached a screenshot of part of the csv file so you can see all of the columns. All null values have been replaced with NaN.

How would I display jobs for the state "NY" that were posted in 2018? I've been having trouble because the dates are written in mm/dd/yyyy format, not just the year.

Here are the column names: Index(['Job_id', 'Vertical', 'Company', 'Post_date', 'Fill_date','Time_to_fill', 'Salary', 'Location', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'County','Region_state', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'], dtype='object')

is_NY_2018 = Master_Clean['State'] == 'NY'
print(is_NY_2018)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-where/

Answer (score 0):

the date here comes as a string so u can split it to get just the year to do what you need to do

```
year = int(Post_date.split("/", 3)[2])
```

## Typecasting to int datatype

you can loop through the `Master_Clean['Post_date']` to get the Post_date values